# How to add checkbox in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to select some specific columns from my grid using checkbox.
So, can anyone give me suggestion that how can i do that?.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  before asking question

Comment: Already asked  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340901/asp-net-gridview-checkbox-selection?rq=1
google it properly and please next time provide some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the templatefield inside the gridview for placing controls .

```
    <asp:GridView ID="familygrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
         <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="check_id" runat="server" />
                   </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link u will get some idea to implement Checkbox in aspgridview

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-with-CheckBox-Get-Selected-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx